# How to remove ?= from url?

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I am getting url example.com/?= and I want this example.com
I have tried .htaccess method but nothing happened.
I have also gone through may link like clean urls but nothing happened
My clean URLs test fail.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will sound silly but it can help you.
Go to `/admin/config/search/clean-urls` 
you will get `example.com/?=admin/config/search/clean-urls` in your address bar
remove `?=` from address bar so that your url become `example.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls`
press enter
Now you will get a check box 
tick that box and save configration.

May this Helps you.

Comment: Really it was so simple. I have been stuck in it for hours, tried every possible aspects on net. Thank you

Comment: Not sure why there was a downvote. Even if it has been answered earlier this is a perfectly valid answer. Adding my +1.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, try enabling "rewrite" module for apache,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After that You need to replace the occurrence of **AllowOverride none** to **AllowOverride all** in your site-available file

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

And finally you need to enable `clean-url` form your drupal site.

> Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata
>
> OR navigate to
>
> http://example.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite apache from httpd.conf

1. open httpd.conf
2. find mod_rewrite
3. just remove # to enable
4. once it enable then you can run Clean URL
5. this will show check box tick on it and save it